# Subtraction by tracking x y coordinates

Tags: matlab

I have set of arrays:

```
x1=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
y1=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
z1=[2 2 2 2 2 9 6 2 2];
```

and

```
x2=[6 7];
y2=[6 7];
z2=[2 2];
```

by tracking x y coordinates, the z arrays have to be subtracted so that output will be

```
x=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
y=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9];
z=[2 2 2 2 2 7 4 2 2];
```

Comment: What? I have no idea how those numbers give the result you want. Can you explain? why do you need `x2` AND `y2`? just with `x2` One can know where on `z` to subtract `z2`. Maybe I just don't get it.....

Comment: x1 and y1 represents a point and z1 some value at that point, similarly for x2 and y2 defines a point and z2 some value. Now i need to match the points in two, if they match then subtract z for the coordinate which is matching. In my case 6,7 coordinates are matching so corresponding z value need to be modified by subtracting i.e. z1-z2.

Comment: uhhhh, I also do not get it, so from an abstract point of deduction, you specified x2 = y2 = [6 7]; and therefore you subtract the 6th and 7th element in z by an amount of z2 (which is [2 2])? So what happens when x2 != y2? Also, what is the point of x1 and y1?

Comment: Actually two surfaces are coming in contact, x,y denotes point on the surface and z height, Now if coordinates of two point is matching then subtract z value only, not x and y.

Comment: Yes, I think @Daniel's solution is the correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the indicies of your elements in `z` using the `ismember` function:

```
a1=[x1.',y1.'];
a2=[x2.',y2.'];
[~,ix]=ismember(a2,a1,'rows')
z1(ix)=z1(ix)-z2
```

To use the `ismember` two matrices `a1` and `a2` are created witch contain the coordinates in rows. Then `ismember` with `'rows'` option is used to get the indices.

When a point exists in x2/y2 which does not exist in x1/y1 the above code will fail.

Comment: well. we have the same understanding of the problem I guess.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for. Many Thanks!!